# Add widget at screen space position egui

Tags: user-interface, rust, egui, eframe

I'm relatively new to egui and I have a project using it and eframe where I'd like a few labels floating within a layout (i.e. not locked to a grid, and able to be dragged to different locations with the mouse) and I have most of the functionality established but I don't know how to set the location of a widget to a screen space position. I haven't found any documentation that describes how to do this and .with_new_rect() has no noticeable effect. Putting the labels within a layout and using ui.add_space() could work but since spacing only works along a single axis it would be too limiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs of [`Ui::label`](https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/struct.Ui.html#method.label) note:

> Shortcut for `add(Label::new(text))`

That is, `ui.label("foobar")` is `ui.add(Label::new("foobar"))`. The docs of [`Ui:add`](https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/struct.Ui.html#method.add) note:

> See also `Self::add_sized` and `Self::put`.

The latter says:

> Add a `Widget` to this `Ui` at a specific location (manual layout).

So, to place a label at a particular position `x`, `y` with size `w`, `h`:

```rust
ui.put(egui::Rect::from_min_max(
    egui::pos2(x, y),
    egui::vec2(w, h),
), egui::Label::new("foobar"));
```

Note that you say "screen space" position, but this is still relative to the window. I assume that's what you meant; otherwise you would additionally have to offset the position by the window's current position.